# What's the most lightweight application to mount iso files in Lubuntu?

Tags: 11.10, mount, lubuntu, iso

I'm looking for a lightweight way to mount iso's on my fresh-install of Lubuntu 11.10. Furius Iso Mount has been my favourite on Ubuntu, but it installs too many extra stuff on Lubuntu, like Brasero. What would be the best choice?

Comment: tried gmountiso?  or just plain sudo mount file.iso /mnt/iso -o loop from terminal

Comment: Jeremy beat me :)

Comment: duffy - didn't mean to steal your thunder. Add a new answer and I'll delete mine.

Comment: +Jeremy, don't sweat it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

gmountiso is light and is basically a gui for the mount command
in a terminal, run `sudo apt-get install gmountiso`

[image]

Comment: My Lubuntu apt was unable to find "gmountiso" package :/  but it did found "acetoneiso" : `sudo apt install acetoneiso`